# Sharepoint 2010 certification material pointers?

Tags: certification, sharepoint-foundation

I would like to give sharepoit 2010 administration certification in next two weeks. I have already spent almost six months on sharepoint 2010 administration and aware of installation,  configuration, bit of sharepoint designer, bit of development, mysite global deployment, email configuration and troubleshooted many issues. I have already completed sharepoint 2007 certifications and spent almost 3 years into sharepoint administration.

What are all the other topics that i should learn before appearing into the exam room?

Any other pointers to learn more about it? Specialy blogs, video materials, podcasts?

Comment: Going to take the exam on coming monday..Found some useful practice questions here www.accelerated-ideas.com/free-70667-practice-exam. Please post some URLs to do a mock test.

Comment: http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/03/answers-for-sharepoint-2010-test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are going to do 70-667 first?

Use this as a guide:

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-667#tab2

As you have the 2007 certs, it should be pretty easy for you, I would suggest studying mostly the features that are new/changed in 2010.

This blog has nearly all the links you need:

http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Exam%2070667%20Study%20Guide/AllItems.aspx

The TS exam is knowledge based, so you need to know "how" to do things, you dont really need to know "why".

Answer (score 1):

You can find the efficient dumps from my blog post http://sharepointcore.blogspot.in/2012/02/sharepoint-2010-certification-dumps.html .

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Learning is the best place for topic details. There are a few books published now on the 2010 test. [Search amazon on sharepoint 2010 exam](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sharepoint+2010+exam&rh=i%3aaps,k%3asharepoint+2010+exam&enc=1&ajr=3)

I posted [my experience](http://tomresing.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20) in November, though not in as much detail as Becky's.